# How can Noether's Theorem be used to prove that the probability density satisfies a continuity equation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, wavefunction, conservation-laws, schroedinger-equation, noethers-theorem

How can I use Noether's Theorem to show that the probability density $\rho (x)=|\psi(x)|^2$ for a wave  function $\psi(x)$ satisfies the continuity equation $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla \cdot\vec{j}=0$, where $\vec{j}$ is the probability current defined in quantum mechanics?

I have solved this problem before by other means but I don't think I understand Noether's Theorem well enough to apply it in this case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something in the back of my mind says there is a quantum version / tweak of Noethers theorem, but I hope I don't lead you astray if the classical version works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem_(disambiguation)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First note that Schrödinger's equation can be understood to come from an action. The Lagrangian is
$$L = \int~\mathrm d^3x \,\,\psi^†(x) \left(i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} - \frac{\nabla^2}{2m}\right)\psi(x) - \psi^†(x)\psi(x)V(x)$$

The Euler-Lagrange equation for $\psi^†(x)$ is exactly the Schrödinger equation. Since the dynamics of $\psi(x)$ are determined by Lagrangian mechanics in this way, Noether's theorem applies without any caveats.^^

In particular, this Schrödinger Lagrangian has a $U(1)$ symmetry corresponding to $\psi(x) \mapsto e^{i\alpha}\psi(x)$. The corresponding conserved charge current density is
$$\rho = j^0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\psi}}\delta \psi  = \psi^†\psi(x)$$
$$\vec{j}^i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial_i\psi}\delta \psi+\frac{\partial L}{\partial_i\psi^†}\delta \psi^†=\frac{i}{2m}\left((\partial^i\psi^†)\psi-\psi^†\partial^i\psi\right),$$
which is the well-known probability current density.

^^ In non-relativistic quantum mechanics the wavefunction $\psi(x)$ is a "classical" variable in that it is simply a function from space and time to $\mathbb{C}$. Noether's theorem works exactly the same for it as in classical mechanics. In quantum field theory the relevant objects $\psi(x)$ become quantum operators and the usual arguments have to be modified somewhat.

Comment: +1 you might mean, **with** caveats in your post. No big deal on this question, just a yes/no/ don't know   reply is fine   but with fields as  operators,  would the Ward identities make any kInd of sense in my comment above,  if you know QFT?

Comment: One minor nitpick: Noether's theorem cannot be used “just” like in classical mechanics, since you can formulate quantum mechanics in the Hamiltonian  as well as Lagrangian formalism (see e. g. the Marsden and Ratiu's book on Classical Mechanics), it simply *is* Noether's theorem.

Comment: Probably we need to use another Lagrangian since your expression doesn't give the **complex conjugate** Schrödinger equation $-i\hbar\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial t}=V\psi^*$. It's important because $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ are not independent, and if the Lagrangian gives different equations for them then we have more restrictions for a solution $\psi$. I suggest to use this form: $\mathcal{L}\left(\psi,\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t},\psi^*,\frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial t}\right)=\left(V-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Delta \right )|\psi|^2+i\hbar\psi\frac{\partial\psi^*}{\partial t}$

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any literature about a Lagrangian for the Schrödinger equation, so I also could make a mistake